# QLogic QLE8152 won't link up with a fiber loop

Tags: linux, ethernet, debian-squeeze

I have a Dell R710 running Debian Linux 6.0 (Squeeze).  I installed a QLogic QLE8152 CNA in the PCI-E riser today and I have been trying to get the CNA's ethernet layer to come up after I put a fiber loop on it; I also scoped it with a light meter, and the SFP+ transceiver is getting the correct amount of light.  The whole time I have been working on this problem, the lights on the CNA are blinking green at a rate of about 1 flash every 3 seconds.

When I plug the fiber into a Juniper EX4500 10GE in a rack next to it, the Juniper's link stays down as well.

I have to confess that this is my first wrangling with a CNA, so perhaps I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but here is what I have found so far...

First the basics...

```
[mpenning@Finger ~]$ uname -a
Linux Finger 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 3 03:59:20 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mpenning@Finger ~]$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l

[mpenning@Finger ~]$
```

`lspci -v` shows that the card is properly installed (physically)

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: QLogic Corp. 10GbE Converged Network Adapter (TCP/IP Networking) (rev 02)
        Subsystem: QLogic Corp. Device 017e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at df8f0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at df900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Expansion ROM at df800000 [disabled] [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [4c] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [98] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [138] Device Serial Number 00-c0-dd-ff-fe-1c-53-b4
        Capabilities: [144] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: qlge
```

The output from `ethtool` shows that `eth4` is the QLE8152...

```
[mpenning@Finger ~]$ sudo ethtool eth4
Settings for eth4:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full 
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Current message level: 0x000060f7 (24823)
        Link detected: no
[mpenning@Finger ~]$ sudo ethtool -i eth4
driver: qlge
version: v1.00.00-b3
firmware-version: v1.35.11
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
[mpenning@Finger ~]$
```

Finally, I tried `modprobe -r qlge; modprobe -r qla2xxx` and then `modprobe qla2xxx; modprobe qlge` to kick the system again... I don't see a smoking gun in `/var/log/messages`...

```
Nov 17 19:46:21 finger kernel: [ 6212.298275] qlge 0000:04:00.1: PCI INT B disabled
Nov 17 19:46:22 finger kernel: [ 6213.779974] qlge 0000:04:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
Nov 17 19:46:33 finger kernel: [ 6224.554074] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: PCI INT D disabled
Nov 17 19:46:33 finger kernel: [ 6224.555322] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: PCI INT C disabled
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.625854] QLogic Fibre Channel HBA Driver: 8.03.01-k6
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.625888] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: PCI INT C -> GSI 35 (level, low) -> IRQ 35
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.626837] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: MSI-X vector count: 7
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.626841] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: Found an ISP8001, irq 35, iobase 0xffffc90012664000
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.627113] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: Configuring PCI space...
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.639429] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: Configure NVRAM parameters...
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.642597] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: Verifying loaded RISC code...
Nov 17 19:46:54 finger kernel: [ 6245.642708] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: FW: Loading from flash (a0000)...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.273340] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: Allocated (64 KB) for FCE...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.273401] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: Allocated (64 KB) for EFT...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.273486] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: Allocated (1350 KB) for firmware dump...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.273856] scsi9 : qla2xxx
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.274631] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.2: 
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.274633]  QLogic Fibre Channel HBA Driver: 8.03.01-k6
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.274634]   QLogic QLE8152 - QLogic PCI-Express Dual Channel 10GbE CNA
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.274636]   ISP8001: PCIe (5.0GT/s x4) @ 0000:04:00.2 hdma+, host#=9, fw=5.01.04 (8d4)
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.274666] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: PCI INT D -> GSI 37 (level, low) -> IRQ 37
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.274748] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: MSI-X vector count: 7
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.274751] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: Found an ISP8001, irq 37, iobase 0xffffc900125c4000
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.275098] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: Configuring PCI space...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.287329] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: Configure NVRAM parameters...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.290624] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: Verifying loaded RISC code...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.290736] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: FW: Loading from flash (a0000)...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.920204] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: Allocated (64 KB) for FCE...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.920264] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: Allocated (64 KB) for EFT...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.920345] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: Allocated (1350 KB) for firmware dump...
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.920749] scsi10 : qla2xxx
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.921715] qla2xxx 0000:04:00.3: 
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.921716]  QLogic Fibre Channel HBA Driver: 8.03.01-k6
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.921717]   QLogic QLE8152 - QLogic PCI-Express Dual Channel 10GbE CNA
Nov 17 19:46:55 finger kernel: [ 6246.921719]   ISP8001: PCIe (5.0GT/s x4) @ 0000:04:00.3 hdma+, host#=10, fw=5.01.04 (8d4)
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.519911] qlge 0000:04:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 34 (level, low) -> IRQ 34
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.533970] qlge 0000:04:00.0: QLogic 10 Gigabit PCI-E Ethernet Driver 
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.533975] qlge 0000:04:00.0: Driver name: qlge, Version: v1.00.00-b3.
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.534856] qlge 0000:04:00.0: ql_display_dev_info: Function #0, Port 0, NIC Roll 0, NIC Rev = 1, XG Roll = 0, XG Rev = 1.
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.534860] qlge 0000:04:00.0: ql_display_dev_info: MAC address 00:c0:dd:1c:53:b4
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.534888] qlge 0000:04:00.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 44 (level, low) -> IRQ 44
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.549109] qlge 0000:04:00.1: ql_display_dev_info: Function #1, Port 1, NIC Roll 0, NIC Rev = 1, XG Roll = 0, XG Rev = 1.
Nov 17 19:46:58 finger kernel: [ 6249.549112] qlge 0000:04:00.1: ql_display_dev_info: MAC address 00:c0:dd:1c:53:b6
```

Any assistance getting a link up on this is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the QLE8152 is only compatable with copper media, IE twinax or ethernet. I have heard rumors that the itel branded 8152 can be made to work with fiber media, but it takes some work.